# Determining limits of integration on double integrals with polar coordinates when integration order is $d\theta dr$

Tags: integration, polar-coordinates

I am trying to understand how to set limits of integration for polar coordinates when the order of integration is $d\theta dr$.

> Use a double integral to determine the area of the region that is inside $r=4+2sinθ$ and outside $r=3−sinθ$.

I know and understand how to set limits for order of integration $dr d\theta$ but don't know how to even begin with setting up limits for $d\theta dr$.

Thanks for any help.

Edit: Any help finding example problems regarding changing the order of integration in polar coordinates is also greatly appreciated.

Comment: Do you know how to find where these polar curves intersect? That's a natural starting point.

Comment: I know that for finding the limits for $\theta$ we should set the two equations equal and solve for $sin(\theta) = -1/3$. But I don't know what to do with these intersection points when the order is inverted.

Comment: What do you mean when you say "the order is inverted"? Also I think you should have $\sin(\theta)=-1/3$? Once you find two consecutive values of $\theta$ that solve this equation you should draw a graph and see how to set up the integral.

Comment: When we are integrating in the order $dr d\theta$, we draw a ray for r limits to see where we enter and exit the region and use $\theta$ limits for rotating the ray. But when we are integrating in the order $d\theta dr$, we should draw a circle using $\theta$ limits to see where we enter and exit the region. I don't know how we determine where we enter and exit the region using $\theta$ limits. I hope I have made my problem clearer.

Comment: I apologize. The question you wrote is clear. I admit I didn't read your question carefully enough. Here is a hint to answer your question. You're going to have two double integrals to evaluate if you wish to use the order $\mathrm{d}\theta \mathrm{d}r$, one for $2\leq r \leq 10/3$ and the other for $10/3\leq r \leq 6$

Comment: So I got how we determine r limits (also drawing the graphs in Desmos) but I am still confused about how to determine $\theta$ values for where we enter and exit the region.